# Tomcat 9.0.82 - Unable to locate defined resources using jndi

Tags: java, tomcat

I've installed Apache Tomcat and active mq properly - both are running on their default port i.e 8080 and 61616 with default settings.

I need to create connection-factory and topic for this I've configured 'conf/context.xml' of Tomcat as below.

```
<Resource name="jms/ConnectionFactory" auth="Container"
      type="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory"
      description="JMS Connection Factory"
      factory="org.apache.activemq.jndi.JNDIReferenceFactory"
      brokerURL="tcp://localhost:61616"
      brokerName="LocalActiveMQBroker"/>
```

Upon booting up the server no issues were reported in Tomcat logs.

Now I've configured the ANT build script such that before building the final EAR package perform Junit. This Junit class 'ResourcesLocatorTest' has a basic job to do - get Initial context, get connection factory, and get topic with jndi name. Upon locating these resources just put a message in the topic and assert it.

```
public class ResourcesLocatorTest {
@Test
public void testJms() throws Exception {
    // Get the initial context
    InitialContext context = new InitialContext();

    // Lookup the connection factory
    ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory) context.lookup("jms/ConnectionFactory");

    // Lookup the topic
    Topic topic = (Topic) context.lookup("jms/Topic");

    // Create a connection
    Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();

    // Create a session
    Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

    // Create a message producer
    MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(topic);

    // Create a message consumer
    MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(topic);

    // Start the connection
    connection.start();

    // Send a message
    TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage("Hello, World!");
    producer.send(message);

    // Receive a message
    TextMessage receivedMessage = (TextMessage) consumer.receive(1000);

    // Assert that the received message is the same as the sent message
    assertEquals(message.getText(), receivedMessage.getText());

    // Close the resources
    consumer.close();
    producer.close();
    session.close();
    connection.close();
}
```

}

When this test gets executed in console NameNotFoundException being thrown - 'jms/ConnectionFactory'

I suspect some connection issue here, since in my JUnit class I haven't defined the tomcat  URL. If yes, how to do it?

Comment: That error is coming because that code can not find the jndi which does not exist in the context. You can use embedded jms as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50471944/175554)